# Is there a name for map projections that produce two disks?

Tags: coordinate-system, history, global

I've seen [lots of world maps](https://www.google.com/search?q=hemisphere%20map&tbm=isch) in the shape of two disks that touch, each one a separate projection of one hemisphere onto a disk -- usually the [Western Hemisphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Hemisphere) and the [Eastern Hemisphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Hemisphere) -- so together the full map covers the entire globe.

Is there a standard name for this kind of map projection onto 2 circular disks?

[image]
from [Wikipedia: Rumold Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumold_Mercator)

[image]
from [Wikipedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1862_Johnson_Map_of_the_World_on_Hemisphere_Projection_-_Geographicus_-_WorldHemi-johnson-1862.jpg)

Ideally I'd like a general name for all "2-disk" arrangements like this,
but I'd be happy with separate specific names for
"2 disks that use a [Wulff net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wulff_net)" and
"2 disks that use a [Schmidt net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_net)" and
"2 disks that use a [Mollweide map](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjInt/ProjIntC/projIntC.html)".

Comment: Nonperspective Azimuthal Projections http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjAz/ProjAzNP/projAzNP.html#AzimuthalEquidistant

Comment: *Any* projection of the sphere that maps a hemisphere into a disk can be made to work like this simply by mapping two complementary hemispheres and placing those maps side-to-side.  Among such projections are the orthographic, stereographic, gnomonic, and azimuthal equidistant.  Most azimuthal projections will map a hemisphere onto a disk.  Perhaps that's why there is not a generic name for such two-disk maps AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [double hemisphere projection](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Double_hemisphere_world_maps).  Here's another [example](http://www.geographicus.com/P/AntiqueMap/World2-sanson-1691) from 1691:

[image]

Comment: That's a nice illustration. However, the question does not ask for a *specific* name, but for a "general" name for all such world maps.

Comment: @whuber Post edited to address comments. A "Double Hemisphere" projection is about as general as it gets--and according to the cartographer of the posted map, pretty accurate (i.e. Deux Plans-Hemispheres").